# Securing access to trigger a azure logic app (HTTP Request Trigger)

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am having a azure logic app which is having a HTTP Request trigger. I am executing the logic app via a web application using Logic App URL.

I have noticed that the Logic App URL is accessible from anywhere. Therefore anyone has the URLcan call the logic app.

I want to know how to secure access to trigger a azure logic app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Azure logic app`, the `URL` generated for `When a HTTP request is received` has a shared access signature, it has been certified and protected, and this process is done automatically by the `Azure logic app`.

```
https://prod-07.westus.logic.azure.com:433/workflows/{logic-app-resource-ID}/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-10-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig={shared-access-signature}
```

For more details, please refer to [What about URL security?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-http-endpoint#q-what-about-url-security)

[image]